# my login system is not redirecting me or at least registering me

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

index.php

```
<html>
 
<body>
    <h1>signup form</h1>
    <form action="register.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="username">
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
 
</html>
```

db.php

```
<?php
 
class db
{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pwd;
    private $dbname;
 
    protected function connect()
    {
        $this->host = "localhost";
        $this->user = "admin";
        $this->pwd = "123";
        $this->dbname = "oop";
 
        $conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pwd, $this->dbname);
        return $conn;
    }
}
```

register.php

```
<?php
 
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $uid = $_POST["uid"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
 
    include "db.php";
    include "registration.php";
    include "register-contr.php";
    $signup = new SignupContr($uid, $pwd);
 
    $signup->signupUser();
 
    header("location: index.php?error=none");
    exit();
}
```

registration.php

```
<?php
 
class Signup extends db
{
    protected function setUser($uid, $pwd)
    {
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare('INSERT INTO users (uid, pwd) VALUES (?, ?);');
 
        $hashedpwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 
        if (!$stmt->execute(array($uid, $hashedpwd))) {
            $stmt = null;
            header("location: ../index.php?error=stmtfailed");
            exit();
        }
 
        $stmt = null;
    }
}
```

register-contr.php

```
<?php
 
class SignupContr extends Signup
{
    private $uid;
    private $pwd;
 
    public function __construct($uid, $pwd)
    {
        $this->uid = $uid;
        $this->pwd = $pwd;
    }
 
    public function signupUser()
    {
        if ($this->emptyInput() == false) {
            header("location: ../index.php?error=emptyinput");
            exit();
        }
 
        if ($this->invalidUid() == false) {
            header("location: ../index.php?error=username");
            exit();
        }
 
        $this->setUser($this->uid, $this->pwd);
    }
 
    private function emptyInput()
    {
        $result = "";
        if (empty($this->uid) || empty($this->pwd)) {
            $result = false;
        } else {
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }
 
    private function invalidUid()
    {
        $result = "";
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $this->uid)) {
            $result = false;
        } else {
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

the problem is it is stuck on register.php and does not redirect me to the index.php and it does not sign me up in the mysql database.

the expected behavior is: it will sign me up(add my username and password to the mysql database) and after that will redirect me to the index.php file(the homepage)

Comment: @RohitGupta what do you mean? it does not signing me up in the db.

Comment: I misunderstood.  Do it step by step.  First prove that it is going to register.php (by having a simple echo in it).  Then, have you looked the values of the _POST variables ? Etc

Comment: @RohitGupta what? in the form it goes to register.php and the value of $_POST is the data that is sent from the form...

Comment: Its not doing what you want, so the normal debugging is to prove all your assumptions. Have you proved that it goes to register?

Comment: @RohitGupta yes in the form in index.php! there is action="register.php" i do not understand what do want from me

Comment: Please ponder on it.  You havent proved that it goes to register.php.  You havent proved that the values in _POST are correct.  You havent proved that your db code is valid.  As part of debugging you have to prove each of those steps.  Otherwise you don't know where it is failing.  Just because the code is there (including the form->action), it does not mean that it works.  Sorry, I can not explain it any better.

Comment: Try this technique: https://rubberduckdebugging.com/

Comment: hahaha - @ADyson ... love that!

Comment: You appear to be mixing mysqli methods and PDO? `$stmt->execute(array($uid, $hashedpwd))` I would associate with PDO

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius it sounds ridiculous (on purpose obviously) but the concept behind it is pretty sound :-)

Comment: Totally - it does indeed work and I have done this before but not heard the term before

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius it does in 8.1+ thanks to none other but Dharman, who implemented it (probably with some help from nikic).

Comment: oh, thanks for the info @YourCommonSense - I'm still on v7+ so was not aware of that!